# $(document).ready being called twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, flipclock

I have a page, with a timed test. I'm using FlipClockJS for the timer, and I have a text box where the user can input a time of their choosing. The input box(.set) code looks like :

```
  $(this).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var setme = $('.set').val();
    set2 = parseFloat(setme); //this is inefficient
    alert(set2);
    $('.set').val(set2); 
    clock.setValue(set2);

   }
  });
```

When I call this script, the alert gives me the right value I want, however it goes back and re-runs document.ready for some reason (I know this as I put an alert after document.ready to see when it fires) thus undoing all my hard work.

I don't know why this is happening. Document.ready only gets recalled when this script is run on the page.

---

Here's the full page

```
var clock;
var set2 = 60;
var slideNum = 1;
var ansPress;

$(document).ready(function() {
  alert('pageload');
  // Instantiate a counter
  clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), set2, {

    clockFace: 'Counter',
    countdown: true,
    autoStart: false

  });

  var timer = new FlipClock.Timer(clock, {
    callbacks: {
      interval: function() {                
        var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
        if (time == 0 && slideNum != 11) { //when we finish the countdown
          clock.setValue(set2); //set the clock to the number in the text box
          $('.carousel').carousel('next'); //move to the next slide
          slideNum ++;
        }
        else if (slideNum == 11 ) { 
          timer.stop();
        }
        else {
          clock.decrement(); //move the clockdown 1 if not at 0
        }
      }

    }
  });

  $(this).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var setme = $('.set').val();
    set2 = parseFloat(setme); //this is inefficient
    alert(set2);


   }
  });

  // Attach a click event to a button a increment the clock
  $('.increment').click(function() {
    clock.increment();
    set2++;
    $('.set').val(set2); 
  });

  // Attach a click event to a button a decrement the clock
  $('.decrement').click(function() {
    clock.decrement();
    set2--;
    $('.set').val(set2); 
  });

  //if you click answers, go to the answers page 
  $('.answers').click(function() {
  $('.carousel').carousel(12);
  ansPress = 1;
  });

  //start the timer 
  $('.start').click(function() {

  timer.start();
  //move to the next slide if it's the first time you've pressed it
  if (slideNum == 1 ) {
    $('.carousel').carousel('next');
  }  
  //toggle buttons
  $( '.start' ).prop( "disabled", true );
  $( '.pause' ).prop( "disabled", false );
  });

  //pause
  $('.pause').click(function() {
    timer.stop();
  //toggle buttons
  $( '.start' ).prop( "disabled", false );
  $( '.pause' ).prop( "disabled", true );
  });
});
```

Comment: try `$(this).keypress(function(event)` => `$(document).keypress(function(event)`

Comment: And I see you are misusing a lot of `this`... Head up to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work

Comment: Yeah, I don't really know what I'm doing. I tried your document substitution and didn't work. Neither does going back to basics
ie 

  $('.set').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    var setme = $('.set').val();
    set2 = parseFloat(setme); //this is inefficient
    alert(set2);
   }
  });

Annoyingly I DID have this working at some point previously but I broke it and can't see how or when or where

Comment: Well hitting enter could cause a form to resubmit which causes the page to reload. So cancel the default action of enter

Comment: OH! It's this ! How do I stop that happening !

Comment: Use [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: FIXED. I effing love you two!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cancel the default action of hitting enter

```
$(this).keypress(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

or if you are not actually using forms, than get rid of the form and submit button.